# Custom Python build system not live printing to console during build

Tags: python, sublimetext3, anaconda

I recently switched python distributions to [Anaconda from Continuum Analytics](https://store.continuum.io/cshop/anaconda/). After installing Python 3.3, I created a build system for use with Sublime (3):

```
{
    "cmd": ["python.exe", "$file"],
    "path": "D:/Users/bsouthga/AppData/Local/Continuum/Anaconda/envs/py33/",
    "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.py",
}
```

It runs scripts fine, except for the fact that output is only printed upon completion of the build. How can I enable normal (live) printing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible that you need to run the script in "unbuffered" mode via the [`-u`](http://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-u) flag.

> Force the binary layer of the stdout and stderr streams (which is
>   available as their buffer attribute) to be unbuffered. The text I/O
>   layer will still be line-buffered if writing to the console, or
>   block-buffered if redirected to a non-interactive file.

This solution isn't specific to Anaconda, but may still be the issue.